# How to migrate Google Earth "My Places" to a new computer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sync, google-earth

Am using Windows 7, latest Google Earth (7.1.1.1580 as of today).

I am migrating to a new computer.

I have copied over the following directories:

C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\LocalLow\Google\GoogleEarth
and
C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Google\GoogleEarth

But the "My Places" dont show up.

Yes, I know I can save "My Places" from one computer and load it in another.
But I dont want to do that. I actually want to do a "sync" between two
installations of Google Earth, by using Bittorrent Sync.

So I need to know which directory needs to be kept in sync for Google Earth to 
be happy.

Surprisingly, I did a google search on this topic and not a single suggested
solution worked!